# Lucene boost: I need to make it work better

Tags: lucene

I'm using Lucene to index components with names and types. Some components are more important, thus, get a bigger boost. However, I cannot get my boost to work properly. I sill get some components appear later (get worse score), even though they have a higher boost.

Note that the indexing is done on one field only and I've set the boost to that field alone. I'm using Lucene in Java.

I don't think it has anything to do with the field length. I've seen components with the same name (but different type) get the wrong score.

Comment: Can you post some code?  Both on the indexing side, and the search side.  At least what the query looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Searcher.explain](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#explain(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int)) to find out how the scores for each document are derived. One of the key criteria in score is length of the field. A match in shorter field gets higher score.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) to see exactly what is stored in your index. Are you using document boosting? See the [scoring documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/scoring.html) to check possible explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Boost is just one factor in the Lucene score for a hit. But it should work. Can you give a more complete example of the behavior you are seeing, and what you would expect?

Comment: I also encounter another problem: after removing and adding a document (for updating) it goes down in the list of results. I'll see if I can arrange a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, boosting is intended to make one field more important than another. If you have only one field, boosting won't change the order of the results at all.

added: no, looks like you can indeed boost specific documents. oops!

Comment: My experience says it does affect the general position. Besides, the doc has a setBoost method (which sets all the fields). What's the point in that when the boost only affects fields?

Comment: Looks like you're right, its there, and the docs do indeed say it will behave as you describe. I guess it just wasn't something I stumbled across in my previous usage.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure field.omitNorms is set to false on the field you want to boost.

Comment: Yes, it is, but thanks. Besides, I can see that it has an affect, just not that great.